# Select td elements if checkbox is on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table, from which i'd like to select all the `td` elements value if the checkbox is `checked` and then put all the elements in some array or string, so that i can transfer it to server side.

```
<table id="tableDg">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chkbCsm" ></input></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{name}">{name}</input></td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="nameText" readonly="true" value="{host}">{host}</input></td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what i am doing on jquery side, but it does the selecting thing irrespective of the checkbox being on. Please somebody help me get it in some array.

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
    $(this).find('td').each( function( index, item ) {
       if ( $(this).has(':hidden') ) {
           alert( $(this).find(':hidden').val() );
       }
    });
});
```

**Added** a jsFiddle link

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/vAYFL/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tableDg tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
    if ($('input.chkbCsm', this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('input:hidden', this).each(function() {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if checkbox is checked or not in your code.

```
if($(".chkbCsm:checkbox").is(":checked")
{
   $(this).find('td').each( function( index, item ) {
     if ( $(this).has(':hidden') ) {
       alert( $(this).find(':hidden').val() );
     }
   });    
}
```